# How to vertically compare a multidimensional list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a grid like shown below:

```
[['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'],
 ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
 [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,'|1'],
 [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,'|2'],
 [1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,'|3'],
 [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,'|4'],
 [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,'|5'],
 [1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,'|6'],
 [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,'|7'],
 [1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,'|8']]
```

And what I'm trying to achieve is to vertically compare cells in a row with the next row below or above it. The idea is that the program should not accept more than 2 ones or zeros above or below each other.

The following code is what I currently made myself, but it's not always working and is definitely not efficient. What it does it that it compares the input on a chosen column and compares it with the next 2 rows.

```
positie = 0
while positie <= 7 and horizontaal == False:
    if puzzel[2][kolom] == puzzel[3][kolom] and puzzel[3][kolom] == puzzel[4][kolom]:
        positie = positie + 1
        print('You entered an invalid input.')
        print('Note: 1's and 0's cannot appear more then twice vertically and horizontally')
        puzzel[rij][kolom] = puzzelbackup[rij][kolom]
        break
    elif puzzel[3][kolom] == puzzel[4][kolom] and puzzel[4][kolom] == puzzel[5][kolom]:
        positie = positie + 1
        print('You entered an invalid input.')
        print('Note: 1's and 0's cannot appear more then twice vertically and horizontally')
        puzzel[rij][kolom] = puzzelbackup[rij][kolom]
        break
    elif puzzel[4][kolom] == puzzel[5][kolom] and puzzel[5][kolom] == puzzel[6][kolom]:
        positie = positie + 1
        print('You entered an invalid input.')
        print('Note: 1's and 0's cannot appear more then twice vertically and horizontally')
        puzzel[rij][kolom] = puzzelbackup[rij][kolom]
        break
    else:
        positie = positie + 1
```

Would someone be able to give me a hint on how to do this effectively?

EDIT1: Ok so someone asked for an invalid grid and a valid grid.The grid that you are seeing at the top is the solution to a binary a puzzle. An invalid grid is shown below(Notice the 3 1's that are below each other, should not be possible according to the game rules):

```
[['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'],
          ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
          [0,".",0,".",1,".",".",".",'|1'],
          [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",'|2'],
          [".",".",".",".",".",1,1,".",'|3'],
          [0,0,".",".",1,".",".",".",'|4'],
          [0,".",".",".",".",".",1,0,'|5'],
          [".",".",".",1,".",".",".",".",'|6'],
          [".",".",".",1,1,".",".",".",'|7'],
          [".",".",".",1,".",".",".",0,'|8']]
```

Comment: Hi, you may want to be a bit clearer on the desired program behavior, perhaps with some simple examples of both valid and invalid grids?

Comment: @YS-L Hello. I'm creating a binary puzzle and the player will be presented with a semi empty grid. Kind of the same idea as sudoku. The player will be able to choose a location for example 2(row)A(column)0(or 1 depending on what the player wants to enter) The rules of the game are that you have to fill the grid with 1 and 0 but there can not be more then 2 ones or zeros horizontally or vertically. Now horizontally wasn't such a big issue to solve but I've been trying to fix the vertical issue for hours.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a class to define your grid, then use class methods to do your comparison

Comment: @wnnmaw Could you give an example of that? I'm pretty new to python in general and am unfamiliar with classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement that the puzzle "should not accept more than 2 ones or zeros above or below each other" is the same as saying that there should never be a sequence of 3 or more zeros or ones.

This means you can iterate over the rows taking blocks of three items and checking to see if they are all the same.

Here is one way to do that:

```
# simplify the grid by making all items strings
puzzle = [
    ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'],
    ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
    ['.','1','.','.','1','1','1','0','|1'],
    ['1','.','.','1','0','0','.','0','|2'],
    ['1','0','.','0','1','1','.','0','|3'],
    ['0','0','1','.','1','1','.','1','|4'],
    ['0','0','0','1','1','0','0','0','|5'],
    ['1','0','0','0','0','.','0','.','|6'],
    ['1','1','0','.','.','.','.','.','|7'],
    ['1','0','1','1','1','.','1','0','|8'],
    ]

for row in puzzle:
    print(' '.join(row))

print()

for column in range(len(puzzle[0])):
    if column >= 2:
        # check rows, starting at the third column of the grid
        for row in range(2, len(puzzle)):
            # take three items and put them in a set
            block = set(puzzle[row][column - 2: column + 1])
            # check that the row block is valid and complete
            if len(block) == 1 and '.' not in block:
                print('ERROR: row %s, columns %s-%s' % (
                    row - 1, puzzle[0][column - 2], puzzle[0][column]))
    # check columns, starting at the third row of the grid
    for row in range(4, len(puzzle)):
        # take three items and put them in a set
        block = {puzzle[row - 2][column],
                 puzzle[row - 1][column],
                 puzzle[row][column]}
        # check that the column block is valid and complete
        if len(block) == 1 and '.' not in block:
            print('ERROR: column %s, rows %s-%s' % (
                puzzle[0][column], row - 3, row - 1))
```

Comment: Hello, your code has helped me very much. The only problem I have at the moment is that it doesn't check the first row. How can I make it so that it also detects errors starting from the first row to the third row?

Comment: Also, my horizontal check doesn't work anymore. It looked like this:         horizontaal = False
        if  "0, 0, 0" in str(puzzel) or "1, 1, 1" in str(puzzel):
            print('Je hebt een verkeerde invoer gegeven.')
            print('Let op: er mogen niet meer dan 2 dezelfde cijfers horizontaal of verticaal voorkomen')
            puzzel[rij][kolom] = puzzelbackup[rij][kolom]
            horizontaal = True

Comment: @Ziplay. I've expanded my solution to check both rows and columns. I don't know what you meant by your first comment: it *does* check the first to third row. The loop **counter** starts at the third row, but the blocks always start two places before that (i.e. from `counter - 2` to `counter`). Anyway, you can see from the messages that all the errors are found.

Comment: I love you. Works like a charm after some editing to fit my program.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient solution, but it is effective, short, and readable.

```
def checkpuzzle(puzzle):
    """
       return True if puzzle does not have 111 or 000 either vertically or horizontally,
       False otherwise.
    """
    def checkline(line):  # False if line has 111 or 000 in it.
        line = ''.join(map(str, line)) # strings are easy to search for patterns in 
        return line.find('111') < 0 and line.find('000') < 0
    # check all rows, and then all columns if necessary
    # zip(*puzzle) is the transpose of the puzzle (ie. row becomes columns)
    return all(map(checkline, puzzle)) and all(map(checkline, zip(*puzzle)))
```